# What exactly should I backup in MongoDB when using replica sets?

Tags: replication, backup, mongodb

I have several instances of MongoDB replica set servers with a primary and a failover machine for each replica set.

The primary machine makes daily backups by creating an LVM snapshot and copying all the data files to the backup location.

Compared to the size of the data those databases contain (one contains only a few documents which can hardly waste more than 1 MB of stored in JSON format), each backup is huge (3.1 GB), with large files being in `journal` directory, as well as `local.1`.

What files should I actually keep in backups?

All `journal/prealloc.*` ones should not be part of backup, which reduces the backups by 2 GB.

What about others:

- The `journal/j._*`: I suppose they contain the actual journal data, but they are 1 GB large. Is there a way to make them smaller or remove them?
- `local.*`: do I need them to keep replica set configuration?

Comment: Why you don't use mongodump since databases are so small?

Comment: @Antonis: because `mongodump` will ignore replica set configuration (or is there an option to make it backup that too?)

Comment: Replica set configuration is not something that changes frequently. You can just print it to a file once a day using the mongo shell. If you get to the point that restore from backups is needed (i mean that you cant just promote a secondary in place) then the last thing that should concern you is the replica set configuration.